# HTML5 allow user to select font type

Tags: javascript, css, html, fonts, styles

For my JS html5 class I'm trying to create a web page that allows a user to select the background color and whether they want to use SANS SERIF or SANS fonts.  I have the background color working --

```
var inputColor = prompt( "Enter a color name for the " +
    "background of this page", "" );
document.body.setAttribute( "style", "background-color: " + inputColor );
```

I can't figure out how to use the same idea and have them select the font without erasing the new background color.

Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would store the background colour and input colour to variables and then set them both at the same time with setAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

Don't touch the `style` attribute, alter the `element.style.*` properties instead.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "foo";
document.body.style.fontFamily = "bar";
```